# Laragon fatal error when accessing localhost/phpmyadmin/

Tags: php, laragon

I have a freshly installed laragon and its giving me error when I'm accessing localhost/phpmyadmin/ how do I fix it?

```
Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in C:\laragon\etc\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 615
```

Comment: What is the PHP and phpmyadmin version? May be changing the PHP version to 8 might fix it

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432488/php-error-unparenthesized-a-b-c-d-e-is-deprecated-use-either-a)

Comment: I'm using php-8.0.11 and phpMyAdmin-5.1.1

Comment: Oh I got it fixed by deleting the included phpMyAdmin directory and replacing it with the latest one that I downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

Solution (worked for me):

1. delete all files in phpMyAdmin folder located in {INSTILLATION_PATH }\laragon\etc\apps
2. Download phpMyAdmin from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/
3. Extract the downloaded compressed file content in phpMyAdmin folder, directory:  {INSTILLATION_PATH }\laragon\etc\apps\phpMyAdmin
4. Restart laragon and you are good to go.