# Nesting null coalescing operator

Tags: php, nested, null-coalescing-operator

```
<?php
        
        $foo = null;
        $bar = null;
        $baz = 1;
        $qux = 2;
        
        echo $foo ?? $bar ?? $baz ?? $qux; // outputs 1
?>
```

**Hello everyone!**

Here I'm using Nesting null coalescing operator. but why I am getting output 1? can you please explain this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Foo is null, so it skips to bar, which is null. Then it skips to baz, which is 1, and it's done. It never hits $qux.

Comment: @aynber so it means that In ternary when I'll get a TRUE or string value then it will stop and execute that value, right?

Comment: Correct, and it evaluates from left to right

Comment: Since PHP 8.x, nested ternaries require parentheses so you can be sure of the grouping. @NazmulHossainPappu But null coalescing is simple left-to-right, similar to `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @Barmar so should i use like this way? 
echo ($foo ?? $bar ?? $baz ?? $qux); is it best practices?

Comment: No, there's almost never any need for parentheses around the entire argument of an operator or function.

Comment: As I said, nested **ternaries** require parentheses, e.g. `$foo ? ($bar ? ($baz ? $qux : 1) : 2) : 3)`. Null coalescing is not ternaries.

Comment: [Relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61433047/2943403)