# I faced an error when I installed wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an old version of a wordpress website in my pc, I want to use it in wampserver so I add the sql file to it but it shows me an error : Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

So I searched on the net, I found something like downloading new wordpress website and then delete all the folders in old website except wp-content and then replace the other files from the new website. I did it but shows me this error :

> Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in C:\wamp64\www\wp-intranet\wp-content\plugins\php-execution-plugin\includes\class.php_execution.php on line 234

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDsZl.png)

Comment: Luckily you have WAMPServer so you can install and use an old version of PHP for this old WP site.

Comment: Go to the [Backup Repo, its easier to find stuff than on sourceforge](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)  and download an older version of PHP. One that is close to what you were using originally

Comment: How to do that, may I download php version or wampserver version

Comment: You can download each part seperately, so try downloading just a version of PHP that allows this code

Answer (score 0):

The error you have shared is coming from the plugin `php-execution-plugin`
You can check the minimum requirement for using this plugin. The error message indicates version incompatibility. If you deactivate the plugin error should be disappeared.

You can check out the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432488/php-error-unparenthesized-a-b-c-d-e-is-deprecated-use-either-a) to the error you referred